# ggplot geom_bar - bars too wide

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am sorry for the non-informative title.

```
> y=read.csv(textConnection(scan("",sep="\n",what="raw")))
"","org","art","type","length"
"191","gk","Finish","short",4
"147","ik","Attending","short",7
"175","gl","Finish","long",11
"192","il","Attending","long",95
"144","gm","Finish","between",5
"161","im","Attending","between",15
"164","tu","Something","young",8
"190","tv","Something","old",4

> decompress=function(x)x[rep(1:nrow(x),x$length),-ncol(x)]
> exstatus=decompress(y)
```

and then the plot

```
ggplot(exstatus, aes(x=type, fill=art))+
geom_bar(aes(y=..count../sum(..count..)),position="dodge")
```

The problem is that the two rightmost bars ("young", "old") are too thick - "something" takes up the whole width - which is not what I intended.

[alt text http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1272295176088679800.png](http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1272295176088679800.png)

I am sorry that I can not explain it better.

Comment: If your data has no values for "finish" or "attending" under "young" and "old", what do you want then?  Do you want a 3-bar cluster with an empty 3rd bar?

Comment: Perhaps try drawing the graph you want (or just alter the ggplot output). It's really not clear what you want.

Comment: Yes. Basically there are 3 possible bars. For the 3 first clusters, two bars should be visible, for 2 last clusters two bars should be hidden.

Right now I count "young" and "old" twice - hence the thichk bars.

I'll try and explain my self better, with an updated question. Thank you Nicholas.

Comment: You're not counting "young" and "old" twice, the current presentation is the way ggplot2 works. See the first example on http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/position_dodge.html.

Comment: Thank your learnr. That helps me alot. But am I wrong in thinking that this skews the visual reprensentation of the data?. The area of "young" and "old" is twice what it should be. Which the reader will percive.

Comment: The link to `www.imagechicken.com` is broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use facet_grid instead of position="dodge"

```
  ggplot(exstatus, aes(x=art, fill=art))+
  geom_bar(aes(y=..count../sum(..count..))) + 
  facet_grid(~type,scales="free",space="free")
```

[alt text http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1272294360054813000.png](http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1272294360054813000.png)

Comment: just realised that facetting makes the percentage sum to 100 in each facet. This is not good :-|

Comment: Setting margins=T, the new margin ("all" facet) looks good. But then there is all the other facets ....

Comment: Ok - I can always do: geom_bar(aes(y=..count../111)) - where 111 is the total number of cases. but that is not a nice way to do it. especially since i can't get ggplot to accept substituting 111 with a variable name that holds that value.

Comment: The link to `www.imagechicken.com` is broken.