# ggplot2 position='dodge' producing bars that are too wide

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm interested in producing a histogram with position='dodge' and fill=some factor (i.e. side-by-side bars for different subgroups within each bar/group), but ggplot2 gives me something like [the first plot here](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/position_dodge.html), which has a rightmost bar that's too wide and reserves no space for the empty group, which I would like.

Here's a simple case:

```
df = data.frame(a=c('o','x','o','o'), b=c('a','b','a','b'))
qplot(a, data=df, fill=b, position='dodge')
```

From [ggplot geom_bar - bars too wide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708994/ggplot-geom-bar-bars-too-wide) I got this idea, and while it technically produces a bar of the same width, but preserves no space for the empty group:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=a, fill=a))+
geom_bar(aes(y=..count../sum(..count..))) + 
facet_grid(~b,scales="free",space="free")
```

How do I achieve what I want? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default options in `ggplot` produces what I think you describe.  The `scales="free"` and `space="free"` options does the opposite of what you want, so simply remove these from the code.  Also, the default `stat` for `geom_bar` is to aggregate by counting, so you don't have to specify your stat explicitly.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=a, fill=a)) + geom_bar() + facet_grid(~b)
```

[image]